# The sql query in java is not executing

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

```
Statement stm ;
ResultSet rr=null;    
String qu =  "SELECT * FROM Pdet";
stm = connn.createStatement();
rr =  stm.executeQuery(qu);
String nn = rr.getString("pid");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nn);
```

IS THERE any problem with the code ? what i think is that there is a problem with the query, the message box doesn't run !

Comment: Any exceptions popping out?

Comment: You need to call `ResultSet.next()` before you can use `getString()` Please go through a JDBC tutorial.

Comment: The query might produce JDBC level errors that you should handle properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(rr.next()) {
    String nn = rr.getString("pid");
....
```

The ResultSet is a pointer initially directed before the first row of your result rows.  You need to point to your results via call(s) with the ResulSet interface's next() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing one step: Moving the cursor to a record:

- `rr.first()` will move the cursor to the first record
- `rr.last()` will move the cursor to the last record
- `rr.beforeFirst()` will move the cursor to the table header (before the first row).
- `rr.afterLast()` will move the cursor to the table footer (after the last row)
- `rr.next()` will move the cursor to the next record
- `rr.previous()`  will move the cursor to the previous record

Please take a look to [The Java Tutorials: JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).